# jQuery + Ajax form submission, PHP doesn't get any data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit a form that only has a radiobutton group with `name=radiob`. This is the script I am using for submitting data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#myForm").submit(function() {
            var dataString = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php?p1=<?php echo $_GET['p1']; ?>",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $("#ppm").fadeOut("slow");
                    $("#ppmPlugin").load('?p1=<?php echo $_GET['p1'];?>&result=true');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

But this is what I get in my PHP script:

`$_POST` array - empty

```
Array ( )
```

`$_GET` array

```
Array ( [p1] => xxx [result] => true )
```

But if I `alert(dataString);` I get `radiob=2`, that is, the value depending on the radiobutton selected..

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: try edit this line 1st and see how:  $("#ppmPlugin").load("?p1=<?php echo $_GET['p1'];?>&result=true");

Comment: That worked! now i am using success: function(html) {
                            $("#ppm").fadeOut("slow");
                            $("#ppmPlugin").html(html);
                        }

Comment: can you explain why didn't that work?

Comment: try copy the line I gave and paste: $("#ppmPlugin").load("?p1=<?php echo $_GET['p1'];?>&result=true");

Comment: Ok... I get it.. I made another AJAX request and thought that the form wasn't working while it was :D :D Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code and it works fine. Perhaps you have some kind of redirect in `index.php?p1=xxx`.

P.S. Tested with this code:

```
<?php $_GET['p1'] = 1; ?>
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="radio" name="radiob" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" name="radiob" value="2" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#myForm").submit(function() {
            var dataString = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php?p1=<?php echo $_GET['p1']; ?>",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });  
</script>
```

And in index.php I have

```
<?php var_dump($_GET, $_POST); ?>
```

Comment: $("#ppmPlugin").load("?p1=<?php echo $_GET['p1'];?>&result=true");

Comment: the above statement prints the post array and the get array

Comment: I fixed my issue by removing the statement and using function(html) { $("#ppm").fadeOut("slow"); $("#ppmPlugin").html(html);

Comment: .load() is just a GET call, you can't get POST data from it, unless you have some logic to store previous POST data and return it on GET call with &result=true param.

Comment: Ok... I get it.. I made another AJAX request and thought that the form wasn't working while it was :D :D thanks :)